# Sql Query Parameter Name Must Be Defined

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Hello I have this SQL query:

```
SQL = "SELECT SUM( " + "CASE WHEN rn =1" + "THEN v.FirstAmount" 
      + "WHEN rn =2" + "THEN v.SecondAmount " + "ELSE v.ThirdAmount " + "END ) " 
      + "FROM (" + "SELECT cv. * , @rn := IF( @vi = `Violation ID` , @rn +1, 1 ) AS rn,          
       @vi := `Violation ID` " + "FROM class_violation cv" + "CROSS JOIN (" 
      + "SELECT @rn :=0, @vi := ''" + ")CONST" + "ORDER BY `Violation ID`" + ")cv" 
      + "JOIN violation v ON cv.`Violation ID` = v.`Violation ID` " 
      + "JOIN class_record tr ON cv.`Class No.` = tr.`Class No.` " 
      + "WHERE tr.`Class ID` = '" + where + "'";
```

---

And I get this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal Error encountered during
command execution ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter
'@rn' must be defined
 at
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection
parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql,
    MySqlParameterCollection parameters,MySqlPacket packet)
```

How would I correct my SQL query and define the parameter?

Comment: You might get better answers if you pull your SQL query out of the string concatenation mayhem and paste it as a full SQL query..

Comment: Where is your `C#` code? Are you providing `value` for all `Parameters` including `@rn`?

Comment: Additionally, you should parameterize the whole query - your `"WHERE tr.``Class ID`` = '" + where + "'"` is open to SQL injection, for example.

Comment: If I paste the full SQL query it would not let me. It says here in that my question is FULL OF CODE ADD SOME DETAILS ON YOUR QUESTION etc etc.

Comment: @Iqbal yes there are values for the parameters but it will be provided on the SQL query execution.

Comment: @JonSkeet my SQL query is for our exercise.

Comment: You should still get into the habit of parameterizing all SQL. It makes your queries easier to read, and avoids many conversions issues *as well* as protecting you from SQL injection attacks. And you never know when someone will take your "exercise" code and just copy it into a real application. Also, if the *exercise* is to improve your skills, why wouldn't you want to follow the most important best practices?

Comment: @user3233787, don't know if this is related to your problem but your string concatenation may cause you some issues like: `rn =1" + "THEN` - no space between _1_ and _THEN_,  `")CONST" + "ORDER BY` - no space between _CONST_ and _ORDER_, `class_violation cv" + "CROSS JOIN` - no space between _cv_ and _CROSS_

Comment: I get a feeling this is a mix up between variables inside the query and .NET interpreting `@rn` as a parameter to the query itself which must be provided. But it looks like you like to use @rn as a variable...

Comment: @dkozl thanks for pointing that out. I put some spaces on it but still I get the same error.

Comment: @ZoolWay yes that's what I think also. How would I make .NET interpret  it as a parameter? My SQL query is OK on XAMPP but on .NET it gives me the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I know how to answer my question. In my connection string, I just added Allow User Variables = True and it works now!

Comment: Okay, interesting question is if you then can still use .NET command parameters or if this disables it. Of if he is able to distinguish between those two...