# Parameter @ must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

This situation often I met when my query is too long. I have defined parameter @no_registrasi, but it still error.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '@no_registrasi' must be defined.

Here is my code:

```
        void Tombol_cari_simpanan1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=;Database=koperasi;Convert Zero Datetime=True;";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connect = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();
        string query = "select * from simpanan left join anggota on simpanan.no_registrasi = anggota.no_registrasi left join jenis_simpanan on simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan = jenis_simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan where simpanan.no_registrasi = @no_registrasi";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, connect);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_registrasi", int.Parse(textbox_pencarian_no_registrasi.Text));
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader=myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        connect.Close();
        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(query, connect);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        datagrid_simpanan.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        connect.Close();    
    }
```

Comment: You have a call to `myCommand.ExecuteReader` and `mySqlDataAdapter.Fill` - The second one has no parameters defined for it. Unless you really mean to do the same thing twice, you should remove one of them

Comment: @kevin : Not sure but I think in MySQL, they need ``;`` at the end of query

Comment: Thierry V: I try what you suggest, but it doesn't work. @JayV: That's make sense, but I don't know how to add parameter to mySqlDataAdapter. Can you help me in answer section?

Comment: You are calling `connect.Close()` twice. Try remove the first one.

Comment: Check this answer, it really helped me out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21795988/6898760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add the parameter in `MySqlCommand myCommand` object.

But you also query by `mySqlDataAdapter`, that object didn't set any parameter.

from your code of part about `MySqlCommand myCommand` is unnecessary because you didn't use

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader=myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I guess you can try this.

```
void Tombol_cari_simpanan1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=;Database=koperasi;Convert Zero Datetime=True;";
    string query = "select * from simpanan left join anggota on simpanan.no_registrasi = anggota.no_registrasi left join jenis_simpanan on simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan = jenis_simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan where simpanan.no_registrasi = @no_registrasi";

    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connect = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connect.Open();

    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(query, connect);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_registrasi", int.Parse(textbox_pencarian_no_registrasi.Text));
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    datagrid_simpanan.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
    connect.Close();
}
```

**Note**:

I would use `using` keyword to contain

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
```

becasue when `connect` object leave the scope it will call `IDisposable.Dispose()` interface method automaticlly.

```
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=;Database=koperasi;Convert Zero Datetime=True;";
string query = "select * from simpanan left join anggota on simpanan.no_registrasi = anggota.no_registrasi left join jenis_simpanan on simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan = jenis_simpanan.id_jenis_simpanan where simpanan.no_registrasi = @no_registrasi";
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connect.Open();
    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connect);
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_registrasi", int.Parse(textbox_pencarian_no_registrasi.Text));
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    datagrid_simpanan.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
}
```