# How to pass the output parameter for MySQL stored procedure for .net core using Pomelo ORM

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-webapi, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Here is my SP in MySQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetMemberID`(
   IN uname     VARCHAR(128),
   OUT MemberID     INT
)
BEGIN  
   SELECT ID INTO MemberID FROM `Member` Where username = uname;    
END
```

And I am calling SP from .netcore web api project that is using Pomelo ORM.

```
var usernameParam = new MySqlParameter
{ 
   ParameterName = $"@uname",
   DbType = DbType.String,
   Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
   Value = "test"
 };
var memberIDParam = new MySqlParameter
{ 
   ParameterName = $"@MemberID",
   DbType = DbType.Int32,
   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
 };

rContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"Call GetMemberID (@uname=@uname, @MemberID=@MemberID OUT)"
            , usernameParam , memberIDParam);
```

I am getting the following error when used output parameter.

> Only ParameterDirection.Input is supported when CommandType is Text (parameter name: @MemberID)

How can I pass output parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a known issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231) in github ,as mguinness commented

> RelationalCommand.csdon't specify CommandType so it'll default to CommandType.Text which means output parameters won't work.

Here is a workaround ,you could refer to

```
 using (MySqlConnection lconn = new MySqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))                
            {
                lconn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = lconn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "GetMemberID"; // The name of the Stored Proc
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // It is a Stored Proc

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "sherry");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    cmd.Parameters["@MemberID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // from System.Data
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Object obj = cmd.Parameters["@MemberID"].Value;
                    var lParam = (Int32)obj;    // more useful datatype

                }
            }
```

Reference :[How to call stored procedure in Entity Framework Core with input and output parameters using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420707/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core-with-input-and-output-para)